# Which style of hat represents the Spanish language the best?

Tags: españa, español-neutral, ropa

Spanish, as most know (and probably all who are reading this), is spoken in many countries, but the cultures of the speakers differ widely, especially between Spain and Latin America.

What I want to know is whether there is a hat/sombrero that represents Spanish speakers in a general sense. e.g., a "Mexican hat" would represent Mexico well, which is the country most in the U.S. associate the Spanish language with. Whereas an item of headgear that cries out, "Spain!" is the bullfighter's cap.

Representing Spanish speakers with one may "disenfranchise" others - IOW, Mexicans may not feel much connection with a toreador's headgear, and Spaniards may feel the same (negative) way about a Mexican sombrero.

So: Is there a "global" sort of piece of headwear that Spanish-speaking people in general might identify with?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because is not about the Spanish language. It is about culture.

Comment: this question should have been migrated to meta.stackexchange before the winterbash started.

Comment: Yeah, and too bad Inigo Montoya didn't wear a hat - that would've been the one!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Be aware that the bullfighter's cap (whose name is [montera](http://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Montera)) is representative of bullfighting *activity* but not the country itself. You can find bullfighting activity in other countries, even in some regions of Spain [bullfighting is no longer allowed](http://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tauromaquia_en_Catalu%C3%B1a#Abolici.C3.B3n_de_las_corridas_de_toros_en_Catalu.C3.B1a). Think about you will found lots of spanish people offended if you associate them with bullfighters.

As typicals hat in Spain you can find [boina](http://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boina), [sombrero cordobés](http://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sombrero_cordob%C3%A9s), [parpusa](http://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parpusa).

Answer (score 1):

I don't really think that there is something like this, because those kind of hats you are speaking of, are very typical according to the culture and not the language.

But It's an interesting question!

I think it would be the same if we want to differentiate English from Britain, USA, Canada, Australia, etc. Is there a hat to represent English speakers?

Comment: Yes, a dunce cap. (just kidding)

Answer (score 1):

I don't think so – You would most probably identify hats with countries, not languages.